# kendoWindow - handling iFrame content response

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm loading a `KendoWindow`'s content as an iFrame according to the following example:

```
<script>
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  content: {
    url: "/userDetails",
    iframe: true
  }
});
</script>
```

Is there some way to add event-handlers to the loading of the content?  I'd like to detect the HTTP response code - for example, if the request returns a 302 I'd like to make the parent window navigate to /login (rather than the iFrame window)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you must use an iFrame? A typical use-case would be that you are retrieving an entire web page (possibly from another domain), instead of just a page fragment.

Comment: yes that's why I'm using an iFrame

Comment: Pity, otherwise the `error` event would give you exactly what you need. So I think you will probably need to request the content manually yourself instead, handling any errors yourself and injecting the content into window when successful. I don't think want you need is available out-of-the-box.

Comment: interesting idea